# Serialize embedded pair (key/value) instead of object with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to create a custom serializer in GSON that insert a key/value pair in an object, not a new object. For example, supose this:

```
class Car {
    @Expose
    String model;
    @Expose
    Manufacturer manufacturer;
}

class Manufacturer {
    @Expose
    String name;
    @Expose
    String from;
}
```

I want to get then a JSON like this:

```
"car":{
    "model":"beatle",
    "manufacturer":"volkswagen",
    "country":"Germany"
}
```

But no matter how I code the serializer, it insists to create a manufacturer object inside "car"

```
"manufacturer":{
    "name":"volkswagen",
    "country":"Germany"
}
```

How can I fix that, to get only key/value pairs?

PS: I cannot make significative changes in classes, because they are mapping the DB. It is just a example to simulate my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not possible to make what I want with JsonSerializer. I could only make it works OK with the new API of GSON, since 2.1 (TypeAdapter class).

```
public class ManufacturerSerializer extends TypeAdapter<Manufacturer> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Manufacturer m) throws IOException {
        out.value(m.getName());
        out.name("country");
        out.value(m.getFrom());
    }

    /* I only need Serialization, dont use this */
    @Override
    public Manufacturer read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use custom serializer should help.

```
private class ManufacturerSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Manufacturer> {
  public JsonElement serialize(Manufacturer src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.getName()); // or src.name public.
  }
}
```

Refer this: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide/#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Comment: So, it gives me  
"car":{  
    "model":"beatle",  
    "manufacturer":"volkswagen"
}  
But I need to insert "country":"Germany" pair too, and I dont know how to do it at this code

Answer (score 0):

You should define you own [serializer](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) and [deserializer](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) for the `Car` class which will avoid just serializing composited classes in the trivial way but will render just what you need.

That's not hard at all, for example you will define

```
class CarSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Car> {
  JsonElement serialize(Car src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonObject o = new JsonObject();
    o.addProperty("manufacturer", src.manufacturer.name);
    ...
  }
}
```

Remember that you need to register the serializer as explained in documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain, I dont want to create a custom serialize to Car class. Instead, I need to serialize Manufacturer class, because car class have many and many other attributes (that can change, inclusive).